# Why is VS Code saying this PHP code doesn't match signatures?

Tags: php, wordpress, signature, wp-nav-walker

I'm using the code below in a WordPress plugin project. VS Code is giving me an error that says:

```
Method 'Acorn\UI\Mobile\MenuWalker::start_lvl()' is not compatible with method 'Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()'.intelephense(1038)
```

Here's the code snippet that's generating the error (first part of function only):

```
namespace Acorn\UI\Mobile;

class MenuWalker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu {

    private int      $depth = 0;

    public function start_lvl( 
        string   &$output, 
        int       $depth = 0, 
        \stdClass  $args = []
    )  {

        $this->_set_depth( $depth );

        $output .= 
            $this->_dump( '<start_lvl />' )  .
            $this->_dump( $args )
            ;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I followed @Spoody's advice and changed the function to this:

```
namespace Acorn\UI\Mobile;

class MenuWalker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu {

    private int      $depth = 0;

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, \stdClass $args = [] ) {
        $this->_set_depth( (int) $depth );

        $output .= 
            $this->_dump( '<start_lvl />' )  .
            $this->_dump( $args )
            ;
    }
```

...but I still receive the same error. Any other ideas?

**MORE DETAILS**
At @M. Eriksson's request, here's the entire class:

```
<?php

namespace Acorn\UI\Mobile;

class MenuWalker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu {

    private int $depth = 0;

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, \stdClass $args = null ) {
        $this->_set_depth( (int) $depth );

        $output .= 
            $this->_dump( '<start_lvl />' )  .
            $this->_dump( $args )
            ;
    }


    // public function end_lvl( 
    //     string   &$output, 
    //     int       $depth = 0, 
    //     \stdClass $args  = null
    // ) : void {

    //     $this->_set_depth( $depth );
        
    //     $output .= 
    //         $this->_dump( '<end_lvl />' )  .
    //         $this->_dump( $args )
    //         ;

    //     return;
    // }


    // public function start_el( 
    //     string   &$output, 
    //     \WP_Post  $item, 
    //     int       $depth = 0, 
    //     \stdClass $args  = $this->emptyStdClass,
    //     int       $id 
    // ) : void {

    //     $this->_set_depth( $depth );
        
    //     $output .= 
    //         $this->_dump( '<start_el />' )  .
    //         $this->_dump( "ID:", $id )      .
    //         $this->_dump( 'Post:', $item )  .
    //         $this->_dump( 'Object:', $args )
    //         ;

    //     return;
    // }


    // public function end_el( 
    //     string   &$output, 
    //     \WP_Post  $item, 
    //     int       $depth = 0, 
    //     \stdClass $args  = $this->emptyStdClass
    // ) : void {

    //     $this->_set_depth( $depth );
        
    //     $output .= 
    //         $this->_dump( '<end_el />' )    .
    //         $this->_dump( 'Post:', $item )  .
    //         $this->_dump( 'Object:', $args )
    //         ;

    //     return;
    // }


    private function _dump( mixed ...$args ) : string {
        $output = '';

        foreach ( $args as $obj ) {
            $type = gettype( $obj );

            $output .= 
                match ( $type ) {
                    'boolean'   => $this->_tab()  .  $obj ? 'true' : 'false',
                    'string',
                    'integer',
                    'double'    => $this->_tab()  .  (string) $obj,
                    'array',
                    'object'    => $this->_indent_text_block( var_export( $obj, true ) ),
                    default     => $this->_tab()  .  "Type '{$type}' is invalid for an argument to _dump()"
                }  .
                "\n"
                ;
        }

        return $output;
    }


    private function _tab( int $spaces_per_tab = 4 ) : string {
        if ( $spaces_per_tab < 0 ) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException( "Spaces-per-tab parameter < 0: {$spaces_per_tab}" );
        }

        return str_repeat( ' ', $spaces_per_tab * 4 );
    }


    private function _indent_text_block( string $str ) : string {
        $lines = explode( "\n", $str );

        $lines = array_map( fn( $line ) => $this->_tab . "{$line}\n", $lines );

        return implode( "\n", $lines );
    }


    private function _set_depth( int $depth ) : int {
        if ( $depth < 0 ) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException( "Input parameter \$depth < 0: {$depth}" );
        }

        $this->depth = $depth;

        return $this->depth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always post _all_ code (like the original method). Hard to know where the issue is if we only can see your version and not the original. We need to know the exact code you're using (we don't know if that plugin have different signatures in different versions and what version you're using). Don't expect us to guess or assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using types in your `start_lvl()`'s parameters but `\Walker_Nav_menu` is not.

From [the source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/)

```
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null )
```

You need to remove types from your method's parameters

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it gives me the same result...

Comment: In your updated question, `$args` still have `stdClass`, your method must be the same as the one from the source code I posted above

Comment: Spoody, thank you. That worked like a champ.